# What is the technical name and what are the valid characters for the jsessionId token that is often appended by J2EE containers into urls

Tags: url, jakarta-ee

I have observed there are various RFC that describe the limits and constraints for the various components within a URL but i just do not know the name of the token that is hacked onto the end of a URL by J2EE containers that insert a session id token.

```
http://server:maybe port/path?query#anchor;JSESSION_ID=12345.
```

From experience it would appear that this token only ever has a single token.

- Is it just "plain text" or does it have some structure and rules such as a query string ?

Answer (score 0):

The `JSESSIONID` parameter (no underscore character) is usually only called the [session ID](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets11.html), sometimes the *session tracking URL parameter*.

It's a single string token, but its value is [implementation-dependent](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId%28%29). Therefore, no structure or rule is enforced. However, it must follow the [URL escaping scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which means some of the characters it contains might have to be URL-encoded.

Comment: @FH: you have described what it is called not what it is...Its just coincidence that J2ee happens to call it the sessionid. THis "token" existed before j2ee so it must have had a name and standard for the j2ee spec leads to take advantage of it.